# Is there any way to change AG-grid checkbox border width and color without using any Custom Component?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

I'm using AG-Grid to show data in a grid. I want to customize checkbox without using any Custom Component for Checkbox.

I have to make the border slightly thin and change the border color and I'm struggling to do so.

I have tried this:-

```
.ag-theme-alpine .ag-checkbox-input-wrapper {
  font-size: 0.875rem !important;
  font-weight: 10px !important;
  border-color: #b3b3b3 !important;
}
```

I'm able to reduce the height/width of the checkbox by giving it a font-size. But the border color and border width is unaffected.

I also tried using border property-  `border: 0.5rem solid #b3b3b3`. But it didn't work.

Comment: are you using any other `css` libraries? if yes, then that might be overwriting your changes.

Comment: I'm not using any other css libraries. I also tried by inspecting and changing the css from the browser by turning off all the applied classes of Ag Grid

Comment: okay, in my case project had `material-ui css` referred which was overwriting ag-grids checkbox properties, but yea it's possible to change `css` of ag-grid `checkbox` without using component. I don't remember on exact ag-grid checkbox `css` class to which i made the change back then, probably you can try on each classes referred for `checkbox`.

Comment: Could you please mention on which classes you applied CSS?

Answer (score 0):

Ag grid uses icons to show the checkboxes. So you can't change border color and width width css.

However, you can change the icons used for the checkbox altogether using the [custom icons option](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-data-grid/custom-icons/)

Answer (score 0):

This code helped me to apply custom color on selected checkbox in ag-grid.

```
.ag-theme-alpine .ag-checkbox-input-wrapper.ag-checked::after {
  color: rgb(244,116,50) !important;
}
```